# SQL query with summed statistical data, grouped by date

Tags: sql, database, statistics

I'm trying to wrap my head around a problem with making a query for a statistical overview of a system. 
The table I want to pull data from is called 'Event', and holds the following columns (among others, only the necessary is posted):

- **date** (as timestamp)
- **positionId** (as number)
- **eventType** (as string)

Another table that most likely is necessary is 'Location', with, among others, holds the following columns:

- **id** (as number)
- **clinic** (as boolean)

What I want is a sum of events in different conditions, grouped by days. The user can give an input over the range of days wanted, which means the output should only show a line per day inside the given limits. The columns should be the following:

- **date:** a date, grouping the data by days
- **deliverySum:** A sum of entries for the given day, where eventType is 'sightingDelivered', and the Location with id=posiitonId has clinic=true
- **pickupSum:** Same as deliverySum, but eventType is 'sightingPickup'
- **rejectedSum:** A sum over events for the day, where the positionId is 4000
- **acceptedSum:** Same as rejectedSum, but positionId is 3000

So, one line should show the sums for the given day over the different criteria.

I'm fairly well read in SQL, but my experience is quite low, which lead to me asking here.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Only tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: And once you've figured out which RDBMS you're using, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desire results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server has neither timestamps nor booleans, so I'll answer this for MySQL.

```
select date(date),
       sum( e.eventtype = 'sightingDelivered' and l.clinic) as deliverySum,
       sum( e.eventtype = 'sightingPickup' and l.clinic) as pickupSum,
       sum( e.position_id = 4000 ) as rejectedSum,
       sum( e.position_id = 3000 ) as acceptedSum
from event e left join
     location l
     on e.position_id = l.id
where date >= $date1 and date < $date2 + interval 1 day
group by date(date);
```